# I need help on my java program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WordLines {
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");

    String s = sca.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<s.length(); j++)

    System.out.println(s.charAt(j));

  }
}
```

I am trying to write a program that reads certain line from user input and then displays only one word from than sentence to new line at a time.

```
For example
Input: The hill is   very-steep!!

It would print out

The

hill

is

very-steep!!

So far I have done this much!!
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know what to write as my next code that would display the output.

Comment: Look at the `split` method of class `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use method `String::split(String)` by regular expression "\s+"

```
String s = sca.nextLine();
System.out.println("Print out:");
for(final String word : s.split("\\s+"))
{
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

Regular expression `\\s+` means *"One or more whitespaces in sequence"*
Read more about regular expressions you can [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Maybe add some commentary?